# Finding element with Selenium on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate the clicking of "next" on my university's online lecture when the current slide ends as it requires the user to manually press "next" whenever the slide has ended.

Using selenium with python, managed to get to webpage, login and navigate to the lecture slides itself but am unable to progress further

[HTML Element on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/D39DTuzq) trying to element on line 3397

I am trying to get the `elapsedTime / totalTime` and

```
while ( currentSlide != totalSlide )
    if elapsedTime == totalTime
        find and click on 'next'
```

I've tried:

```
duration = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='label time'][@style='display: none;]")
duration = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='.label.time'][@style='display: none;']")
```

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:

Got it working suggested by Lukas

`content = urllib.request.urlopen(URL, timeout=10).read().decode("utf-8")
duration = content.split("<div class="label time" style="display: none;">")[1].split("</div>")[0]`

Comment: Your square-brackets are not balanced.

Comment: I would check it out, if you give me a link

Comment: Can you upload your code? It's hard to tell from those code snippets.

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the HTML and properly format it instead.

Comment: I don't see any element with 'Next'. The element you selected (and the selector you used) is marked with `display: none` which means it won't be visible to the user and Selenium won't click it. You need to post the before and after HTML.

Comment: @jihan1008 edited the post with pastebin link

Comment: @JeffC thank you for telling me screenshot of code is bad idea and the element 'next' is this `</svg><button class="component_base next" type="button" tabindex="-1" aria-label="next slide">NEXT</button></div>`

Comment: Please edit your question and put the HTML there, properly formatted. That way everyone will see it without having to read all the comments.

Comment: Have you tried clicking by linktext = 'NEXT'? You may need to wait for clickable also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried to use a normal parser instead of selenium?
Check this out:

```
content = urllib.request.urlopen(URL, timeout=10).read().decode("utf-8")
duration = content.split("<div class="label time" style="display: none;">")[1].split("</div>")[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

i would try:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC    

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get(URL)
delay = 30  # seconds
WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'label time')))
print("Page is ready!")
# duration = browser.find_element_by_class("label time").text
# --> "InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted"
duration = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".label.time").text

# alternative:
duration = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='label time']").text
```

Comment: tried it and now I get `InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted`

Comment: tried both and now it shows `NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@class='label time']"}` and unfortunately can't give you the link as one need username and pass to access the lecture slides

Comment: ok i try to help you without the link and because of that i can't test it on my own but what is the message while trying find element by css selector?